# Compiled Python app (using Pyinstaller) GLIBC error

Tags: ubuntu, python, development

I am developing a python app and I have compiled to distribute using Pyinstaller,
I am using Ubuntu 18.
I realized that program cannot run in older machine - like Ubuntu 16, 14 and so on. The reason is that the Glibc version of my compiled software is higher than the receiving machine.
So I tried to make the same development in Ubuntu 12 but even installing pyenv in order to have Python 3.6.7 (which is required for some packages that came from Pypi) I am getting lots of error other packages that came from apt-get for instance.

I would like to know any recommendation for this approach.
What is the best solution for this scenario?

I am really thinking to rebuild all my code for Python 2.7 compatibility which will cause lack of functions...but this also will make a time effort and in the end I am not sure I will get a satisfatory results.